# Adding GitHub projects to Careers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I try to add a GitHub repository on Careers (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/github/847) for the "Open Source" section of my profile, it adds a broken item to the "Apps & Software" section instead.

I am using Firefox 18.0.2. These are the steps I follow:

Click on the GitHub icon under "Open Source":

[image]

Click "add" for the repository I want:

[image]

Return to the profile and voilà:

[image]

It is in the wrong place ("Apps & Sofware" instead of "Open Source") and it imported no data.

Comment: Confirmed - thanks! We're looking into this and will provide an update shortly.

Comment: I love that with all this computing knowledge we still haven't developed an app that easily allows people to write a caption on an image and instead we must resort to scrawling with a software pen!!

Comment: @Toby Allen - [It's a meta meme.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/132073)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed! GitHub projects should now get imported correctly again.

Comment: Hmm, now the data does get imported, but the projects still end up in the wrong place ("Apps & Software" instead of "Open Source").

Comment: BitBucket repos get imported to the right place. It's only GitHub repos that go in the wrong place.

Comment: You're right. The GitHub import now pulls all the data, but doesn't put the "Open Source" sticker on your project as it should. Investigating this further...

Comment: Try again, please. Open Source projects should now end up in the correct section.

Comment: It works correctly now. Thanks!