# Add Project on Careers is buggy

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

I've seen the GitHub error here: [Adding GitHub projects to Careers is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168782/adding-github-projects-to-careers-is-broken),  which is marked as `status-completed`. However, I am trying to add a project which is essentially a reference to a live website, and it seems to still be broken.

[image]

Once I click, though, rather than getting any kind of success message, I get this, instead:

[image]

I have, of course, changed the values of the fields in order to protect the innocent. When I use these dummy values (as shown in the screenshot) it saves as expected. When I use the real values, the second screen just keeps reappearing, with no addition to my profile.

In using Fiddler and inspecting the network traffic with Chrome, I've determined the following:

- There is some relationship between success/failure around including `CustomTags` as part of the submission (when a value omitted, some values will go through suddenly).
- If you switch `CustomTags` with `Tags`, the same success as above occurs.
- If you have a `|` value in the Project Name, it seems to fail regardless.

Similarly, when *editing* a project that has already been added, the same changes need to be made, or you get failures. In this case, you will often lose your URL, tags and FavIcon of the project.

Finally, if you include `Tags` rather than `CustomTags`, no tags appear on the actual display, though they appear to be saved successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. I’ll see if I can get a consistent repro on this.

Comment: Replied to your e-mail RE: the bug, Matt. Thanks for reaching out.