# Cannot add urbanairship.com to project on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On Careers 2.0, the "Add Project" button would not work for me as long as I listed urbanairship.com as a project with [this url](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.retailconvergence.ruelala).

The tags I used were:

```
android java git json android-layout android-actionbar android-fragments android-gcm google-wallet urbanairship.com
```

Once I added the project without the urbanairship.com tag, attempting to edit and save the project once I added urbanairship.com would fail.

I was able to add urbanairship.com to other projects successfully.

Comment: That first link is leading to an Android app which seems to have nothing to do with urbanairshiop.com. Also, what error message do you get?

Comment: Looks like a weird bug. I'll forward onto one of our devs.

Comment: There's no error message, it just reloads the screen without formatting (similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174053/add-project-on-careers-is-buggy). The app uses the Urban Airship library and API.

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem with the length of tags - there is a 100 character limit for the Technologies field. On this particular form the error wasn't displaying, and you were taken instead to an unformatted version of the form.

The AJAX validation has now been implemented properly, so you'll see an error message now if your technologies field is too long.