# Adding a google code project to SO Careers profile adds it to the wrong section

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was trying to update my SO Careers profile, and when I now edit it and click on the "Google Code" link to add a Google Code hosted project to my "Open Source" section, it actually adds it to the next section ("Apps & Software").

Comment: Looking into this, probably similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168782.

Comment: @Max: arf, indeed, quite likely a dup. Same behavior for Google Code. I had searched meta first, but apparently not well enough. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed, please try again. You might have to remove your project and then add it back to your profile.

Comment: Works! :) Funny thing though: I had left the badly imported project in and added a description waiting for the fix. Then I removed it and tried again as you suggested, and when it pulled the project into the right section this time, it had kept the custom description I had entered. Not complaining, it's nice and practical and I guess you kept an internal record based on the project's source or ID. But makes me wonder what else you keep temporarily (or not so temporarily).